# Web scraping loop with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to learn Haskell and I have another small project (currently in Elixir) that I'd like to port as an exercise. It is a simple web scraper that scrapes a list of urls.

Imagine having a list of zip codes, around 2500 items. For each entry, a web page should be scraped, in the form of `http://www.acme.org/zip-info?zip={ZIP}`. I managed to write the code to crawl a single web page using Scalpel.

But how would I go about scraping the 2500 items? In Elixir I map over the list of postal codes and after each page request there is a short sleep of 1 second, just to ease off pressure on the targeted website. It is not important to me to scrape the website as fast as possible.

How would I do this in Haskell? I read about `threadSleep` but how do I use that in combination of the list to traverse and the main method, since the sleep is side effect.

Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you already have a function like:

```
scrapeZip :: Zip -> IO ZipResult
```

Then you can write a function with [`traverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse) to get an IO action that returns a list of zip results:

```
scrapeZips :: [Zip] -> IO [ZipResult]
scrapeZips zipCodes = traverse scrapeZip zipCodes
```

But you want to add a delay, which can be done using [`threadDelay`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay) (you can import it from `Control.Concurrent`):

```
scrapeZipDelay :: Zip -> IO ZipResult
scrapeZipDelay zip = do
  x <- scrapeZip zip
  threadDelay 1000000 -- one second in microseconds
  return x
```

And then you can use this `scrapeZipDelay` with `traverse`:

```
scrapeZipsDelay :: [Zip] -> IO [ZipResult]
scrapeZipsDelay zipCodes = traverse scrapeZipDelay zipCodes
```

Instead of defining a whole new `scrapeZipDelay` function you can also write a pretty small version with the `<*` operator:

```
scrapeZipsDelay :: [Zip] -> IO [ZipResult]
scrapeZipsDelay zipCodes = 
  traverse (\zip -> scrapeZip zip <* threadDelay 1000000) zipCodes
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, it makes sense. I'll have to read up on the `<*` operator, but I will keep that for later. Enough to think and learn about already :). Thank you again, I'll give it a go and mark as an answer according to that.

Comment: @JeroenBourgois Not much reading needed, really. If you think of it as being defined as `a <* b = do { x <- a; b; return x }` -- notice the parallels to `scrapeZipDelay` -- you will be wrong only in unimportant ways.